# Spinner help, Eclipses throwing errors!

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, sdk, spinner

I'm having trouble populating my Spinner, so I'm using the tutorial on Google website,

http://developer.android.com/resourc...o-spinner.html

When I get to part 4, and I put the code in the the java folder, a bunch of red X's pop up, giving me errors.

My questions is do I delete everything in the oncreate () .java file and insert the code from Googles site? When I do it give me errors, this is what happens,

http://imgf.tw/206693399.png

I'm know my coding is wrong, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: As name says, CTRL+SHIFT+O will do it.  Plus you are missiing the last closing parenthesis.  Also, when there is a light bulb, associated with the red cross, that means that eclipse can propose some easy fixes.  Click on these bulbs and select your fix.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all the imports right? Try pressing (I think) ctrl-shift-o to lead missing imports for Spinner and ArrayAdapter.